# thermal debroglie wavelength

Tags: quantum-mechanics, astrophysics, water

A recent physics exam at the pre-university level has questions about water-ice forming on the surface of interstellar dust particles. One expression presented in the exam is the thermal debroglie wavelength $$\lambda=\frac{h}{\sqrt{2 m \pi k_\text{B} T}},$$ which is usually applied to free particles in an ideal gas. In the exam this expression is applied to a proton on the surface of an interstellar dust particle with $m$ is the proton mass and $T=10\,\text{K}$ the temperature in an interstellar giant molecular cloud.

Students are asked to use this expression to explain if there is a fair chance that a proton will tunnel across an activation energy barrier with spatial width $a=10\,\text{nm}$ towards a nearby OH group on the surface of the same dust particle, resulting in the formation of a H$_2$O molecule.

My question a: is it valid to apply the above expression to a proton on the surface of a dust particle?

The next question in the exam is about laboratory experiments with $\text{OD}+\text{D}_2\to\text{D}_2\text{O}+\text{D}$ where deuterium D replaces H in the same reaction: "Explain if the tunneling probability with D is higher or lower than with H". Some students use the above expression with a larger $m$, so $\lambda_\text{B,thermal}$ with D is less than with H.

My question b: does a smaller $\lambda_\text{B,thermal}$ result in a higher or lower tunneling probabilty and why?

Comment: What are your thoughts about your questions?

Comment: Question a: the expression for $\lambda_\text{b}$ seems to be valid for free particles in an ideal gas. A hydrogen atom on the surface of a dust particle isn't free, so the expression doesn't seems valid here. If it is used nevertheless in an approximation, that should be mentioned in the examen, in my opinion.

Comment: Question b: the tunneling probability depends on the transmission coefficient $T$, derived from the Schrödinger equation. $T$ depends on the width $a$ and "height" of the barrier, on $m$ and the total energy $E$, not on $\lambda_\text{b}$ as such. So I think a statement like "bigger $\lambda_\text{b}$ means higher $T$" isn't valid. Correct?

Comment: Thank you for giving your thoughts. These are confusing questions, especially for pre-university level. I recommend that you discuss this question in a chatroom.